# Get values from a JSON response in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have a groovy script, it does an easy API call, and I am getting as response a JSON body.
How can I get, from the JSON body, a single value, and use it as a variable?

```
    newRelease.request(GET) { req ->
    requestContentType = ContentType.JSON
    headers.'X-Octopus-ApiKey' = 'API-xxx'

    response.success = { resp, JSON ->

      return JSON

    }

        response.failure = { resp ->
        return "Request failed with status ${resp.status}"

            }
    }
```

and this is the response

`[DeploymentProcessId:deploymentprocess-Projects-370, LastReleaseVersion:null, NextVersionIncrement:0.0.41, VersioningPackageStepName:null, Packages:[], Links:[Self:/api/Spaces-1/deploymentprocesses/deploymentprocess-Projects-370/template]]`

So what I am trying to extract is the `NextVersionIncrement`.
Any idea?

Comment: what is the problem? should be like `respJsonVar.NextVersionIncrement`

Comment: How? ```return "${respJsonVar.NextVersionIncrement}"```

Comment: for example `response.success = { resp, JSON ->

      return JSON.NextVersionIncrement

    }`